# Can I extract Info.plist from a ipa without unzipping it?

Tags: xcode6, plist, ipa

I got a .ipa file, I just want to get the Info.plist inside it, any method can I use to extract the Info.plist from the ipa file without unzip it?

Comment: Seems hard to extract anything from a `zip` without unzipping... How can I take something outta my fridge without opening it?

Answer (score 7):

I use this on Linux to extract content to standard out in a shell:

```
unzip -p "/path/to/file.ipa" '*/Info.plist'
```